# Do Electrostatic Charges build up at the ends of an Inductor in closed circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, conservative-field

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYYNRubHIno) from YaleCourses youtube channel. At around 41.00 minutes, the professor introduces the notion of charge buildup at the ends of an Inductor in a closed circuit.

---

Is the charge buildup a real phenomenon in a current-flowing circuit?

If so, does a conservative field really exists inside the Inductor?

Comment: Everywhere a current changes direction or slows down or speeds up there must be a nanoscopic pile of charges at the corner to push the charges the right way, but nobody really cares about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a charge accumulation and there must be to maintain an electric field.

In fact, there is a uniform [surface charge density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_density) along the surface of the inductor (or on the surface of the coiled wire that the inductor is made of) as well as at the ends too. There has to be surface charge along the inductor to provide the electric field to allow charge to flow along it. This is also the case for other circuit devices like resistors.

We can show that the [current density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_density) $${\bf j}=\sigma {\bf E}$$ in the interior of *any* conductor where $\sigma$ is the [electrical conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) and $\bf E$ is the electric field, which *is* conservative  (there is no reason why it should not be and note that the electric field *inside* any conductor is zero).

Comment: If there is a current in a conductor,  there must also be an E field. The E field inside a current carrying wire is proportional to the gradient of the charge density, which I'm told is on the surface of the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my poor english. My native language is french.

I think these charges are not always present. If you take a long solenoid supplied with sinusoidal current and if you place inside a circular circuit centered on the axis of the solenoid, the induced electric field is sufficient to generate an electric current without any accumulation of charges. But in this last case the circuit is entirely in the magnetic field and the symmetries are very strong. In general, this is not the case.

You could look at this question [Kirchhoff law and Inductors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386611/kirchhoff-law-and-inductors/650835#650835)